# Maya textureWindow force imageRatioValue with python

Tags: python, maya

Is it possible to force the textureWindow(uv editor) using a aspect?
Not using the selected image aspect but a custom ratio.

[Texture Window command](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/CHS/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/textureWindow.html#flagimageRatio)

ImageRatioValue(irv) is only readable.

Comment: have you tried -imageRatio  instead of imageRatioValue, seems you can edit this one

Comment: @DrWeeny Looks like it grabs the ratio of the attached image. I want to force a custom value. Isthat also possible?

Comment: i dont know i was supposing you could force it with the edit flag, apart manipulating the image to get to the specific ration you want, im not sure